# From which plex am I booted from on raid?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, raid, boot, software-raid, raid1

I have a server with mirrored boot volume. It is software raid 1 in Windows Server 2008 R2. I do not have physical access to the server.

I am looking for a way to check which disk is a boot drive. I need a way to check it from os.

How can I do that ?

EDIT:

I know how to do that, but I dont think its proper way.

From diskpart I can break mirror:

```
select volume 0

break disk=0
```

And Windows will only allow me to do that on not current boot disk. I want to check which one is boot without breaking mirroring.

Comment: Ahhhh....If the disks are mirrored, can't you reboot from either disk?

Comment: @ mdpc : I can. What are You trying to say ? I do not have access to bios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From **diskpart** :

```
select disk 0

detail disk
```

You can find info:

> Boot Disk  : Yes

Answer (score 2):

`bcdedit /list` should show you the current boot volume's label and GUID. I can't test this at the moment, as I'm on a train, but it should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @ MDMarra : bcdedit /enum , is that what You are talking about ? I know which volume, but this volume is mirrored on two physical devices. I need to know which disk is a boot drive.